# a long plumed distance/a white sailing sky

Tags: word-meaning

> Down come the cardinal's hunting scenes, the scenes of secular
>   pleasure: the sportive peasants splashing in ponds, the stags at bay,
>   the hounds in cry, the spaniels held on leashes of silk and the
>   mastiffs with their collars of spikes: the huntsmen with their studded
>   belts and knives, the ladies on horseback with jaunty caps, the
>   rush-fringed pond, the mild sheep at pasture, and the bluish feathered
>   treetops, running away into a long **plumed** distance, to a scene of
>   chalky bluffs and a white **sailing** sky.

(Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel)

I looked up the dictionary but can't make out the meaning of the two words in the  phrase. Is "**plumed**" supposed to be "**clouded**"? What kind of sky is a white "**sailing**" sky?

Comment: *Plumed* seems to refer back to *feathered*: each tree is *feathered*, and the forest stretches a long way into the distance, *pluming* it with the feathers of the trees. *Sailing sky* is less clear to me. The chalky bluffs would indeed be white, so they could look like *sails* stretched up into the sky, but then the sky would one be sailing, the bluffs would be. So maybe white fluffy *clouds*bade sailing through the sky? As I said, not clear to me.

Comment: The sky can refer to the entire dome above or to just a part of it. The participle "sailing" describes the motion of a section of the sky in the distance (running away into ... a ... distance... to a scene of ... bluffs and a *white* sailing sky); the clouds in the distance are moving with the prevailing winds.  +1 to Dan for "plumed" ->"feathered".

Comment: @TRomano *Sailing* is not here a participle.

Comment: @tchrist: I'd say it's an adjectival participle. What would you say it is?

Comment: @TRomano The word *sailing* is a noun in *sailing skies*, because it is skies made for sailing not skies which are sailing. That’s why *sailing* is here a noun not an adjective. See my answer.

Comment: @tchrist: plausible to be sure, but in this literary context, "sky suitable for sailing" is hardly as clear as "running shoes"; the logic that if the activity exists in its own right adjectival use is precluded does not apply to metaphorical language or to wordplay. What do you make of the line "Till with them he sailed on the sailing sky" here: https://books.google.com/books?id=ISI1AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22sailing+sky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAmoVChMIwZT4-6rexwIVSYENCh2d4QJM#v=onepage&q=%22sailing%20sky%22&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## “An *X*ing *Y*”: Participles versus Gerunds

The easy thing about *‑ing* words is that morphologically, they are strictly regular. The hard thing about them  is that they shoulder more than one burden in English, and which job they are doing is not always clear to the learner.

Your question suggests that you may be most familiar with using them as participial adjectives, the way one does with *running jokes* and *running water*.  This is a *running* that corresponds to the verbal form used in progressive constructions.

> Turn that faucet off: the water is still running!

But there can be more to them than just that alone.

### Relationship Management for *‑ing* Words

The way that English *‑ing* words placed before nouns can sometimes serve as adjectives and sometimes as other nouns can be a surprising or stumbling block to learners. There is no guaranteed way to immediately know which of the two is intended.  Only context and knowledge of the subject domain makes clear which is which with collocations like:

> - running shoes
> - running shorts
> - running water
> - running hemlines
> - running late
> - running scared

However, one reasonable rule of thumb that often works when you want to determine what is really going on with an “*X*ing *Y*” pair is to flip the order of *X* and *Y* and see whether *is* or *for* makes more sense between them.

In other words, is it really a **“*Y* for *X*ing”**, or is it instead a **“*Y* which is *X*ing”**? Look to answer that question whenever you see a new *Xing Y* combination you’ve never seen before.

#### The “is” relationship for adjectives, participles

With *running hemlines* and *running water*, the *‑ing* word enjoys an “is” or “is doing” relationship with its noun.  Used in this way, you can give it adverbs or complements, since it can still be put to use as a verb:

> The water quickly running down her cheek looking like so many tears.

#### The “for” relationship for nouns, gerunds

However, that is not the type of use that *sailing* is being put to here. Rather, *sailing* is an activity in its own right, just like *running* can be;  consider *running shoes* or *running track* or *running shorts*.

Activities like *running* and *sailing* are not adjectives but nouns, which means that *sailing* cannot be a participle.  It is a gerund — or perhaps better, a deverbal noun, one that has wrung dry of  all its “verbness”.

An *‑ing* word used as a noun enjoys a “for” relationship with the noun it modifies. The skies are not themselves sailing; rather, they are skies made for sailing.

> - These shoes are great for competitive running.
> - These skies are great for competitive  sailing.

Once it stops being a verb, it cannot do verb things any longer. It does noun things, like take adjectives as modifiers as just shown immediately above.

## The Fine Print

In some cases, the distinction is far less clear than in *running water* and *running shoes*. The opposition between *-ing* words acting as participial adjectives and as deverbal nouns is not a binary one where something is either either one or the other. Instead there is more of a continuum between versions that act more like verbs and ones that act more like nouns.

But that is for another day.

Answer (score 0):

"White sailing sky" is not a phrase I'd ever encountered before, but it's something I read and thought "oh, it's that kind of sky". I interpret it as a sky suitable for sailing under - that is, the weather is good, some wind, not overwhelmingly sunny but not very cloudy either - as well as describing the motion of the clouds themselves.

"Long plumed distance": Dan Bron's interpretation as feathers, metaphorically for the trees, seems right to me. I think it's there for the sound quality as much as anything - it adds to the rhythm of this already beautiful sentence. It's a word I didn't really parse while I was reading the sentence; I read the phrase synonymously with "long distance", although "long distance" sounds drab and slightly weird.